# How to do via fencing of an RF trace with a 5V front copper plane and a GND back copper plane?

Tags: pcb, rf, radio, transmission-line

**Background**

I am a building a board to send RTTY via a Radiometrix NTX2B as part of my final year High Altitude Balloon (HAB) project. I have just created a PCB which I uploaded to JLCPCB for manufacture, but hours later starting to doubt the via fencing I had done with the SMA centre pin to transmitter antenna pin.

Since I have the back copper set as a GND plane and the front copper as 5V plane, as you do, then placed the vias labelled **GND** either side the very short 0.5mm RF trace.

I cancelled my order upon doubting what I did, in case it was a silly mistake, since it was my first time using via fences (or anything to do with RF on PCB). If both the top copper and bottom copper were set as GND planes I wouldn't have this doubt.

Have I just done something stupid, e.g connecting the 5V plane to the GND plane or....?

I emailed by electronics lecturer, but no reply so I thought I ask here for a faster reply since I am close to a deadline. (Please ignore the fact the email was written for a specific person)

I'm starting to think that it may have been okay due to the zone showing the 5v plane avoiding the vias, but I am not certain.

[image: Email to lecturer]

Comment: Is your design microstrip, coplanar waveguide, stripline, or what?

Answer (score 1):

In all the major CAD tools, plane floods will automatically avoid vias of different nets.  That is to say, if you flood a plane with net GND, the plane flooding algorithm will leave a gap around the via of net 5V.  The size of the gap is determined by the spacing rules you set up (either for the plane itself or the nets/net classes involved).

If you run a design rules check it will usually tell you if you have pieces of copper touching that are different nets.

Your screen shots look like KI-CAD.  If so, then you should be OK as long as the DRC check doesn't complain.  You can also verify visually by looking at the planes in question.  If you see a gap around the via you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for long reply, yes it was kicad. The DRC doesn't given any errors, no. I will reorder now that I feel safe it was okay.